# Angular UI DatePicker popup.html template override resolution changes

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I created a new template to override popup.html in Angular UI Bootstrap. I'm struggling with coming up with a solution for resolution changes.

To change resolution:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> then mouse wheel
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> then <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:Klbek5SpOGIA4FXTmlFX?p=preview

I tried wrapping my template with a div styled relative but that didn't work. I'm going to keep tinkering but any help is appreciated.

```
"<div style=\"position: relative\">" +
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want your new template to be responsive?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to be responsive. I want the calendar to line up with the future date section when resolution changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by resolution, but if you're trying to make it responsive (for different viewport sizes), you might consider a slightly different approach.  Note that any approach is going to be a little bit more effort since the calendar itself is a fixed size (and mixing fixed sizes with responsive is challenging).

I would approach this by changing the entire dropdown structure.  Semantically, an unordered list doesn't really make sense to me in this context.  So, for simplicity and clarity, I used divs.  Also, if you're going for something responsive, **don't forget to add the viewport meta tag**.

Here's how I'd structure the template:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu menu-extended" ng-style="{display: (isOpen && 'block') || 'none', top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}" ng-keydown="keydown($event)">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="col-calendar">
      <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-buttons">
      <h4>Something here...</h4>
      <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click='select(date.setTime(date.getTime()+30 * 86400000).toLocaleDateString())'>30 days</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="showButtonBar" style="padding:10px 0">
    <span class="btn-group pull-left">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="select('today')">{{ getText('current') }}</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="select(null)">{{ getText('clear') }}</button>
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right" ng-click="close()">{{ getText('close') }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then you can use media queries to refine how the dropdown and "columns" display:

```
.menu-extended {
  padding: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .menu-extended {
    width: 100%;
  }  
  .col-calendar, .col-buttons {
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
  }
  .col-calendar {
    width: 65%;
  }
  .col-buttons {
    width: 35%;
  }
}
```

## [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NiVFdGacPu9hliVbqALa?p=preview)